# SQL server: How to Modify a JSON element value in a nested JSON array

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, sql-server-2017

If i have below JSON (@CarDataJsontest) e.g

```
{
  "house": {
    "gate": [
      "Car1",
      "Car911",
      "Car3",
      "Car4"
    ]
  }
}
```

If i need to do is to modify the car911 to car2
all i have to do is below

```
SET @CarDataJsontest= JSON_MODIFY(@CarDataJsontest, '$.house.gate[1]','Car2')
```

Now I have a JSON @CarDataJson which is something like below

```
{
  "house": {
    "gate": [
      [
        "Car1",
        "Car911",
        "Car3",
        "Car4"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

What do I need to do now to modify the car911 to car2?

Because using below Query

```
SET @CarDataJson = JSON_MODIFY(@CarDataJson , '$.house.gate[0].[1]','Car2')
```

i just get an error.

> Unexpected character '[' is found at position X

Comment: You're soooo close. `$.house.gate[0][1]`.

Comment: I think you've got a typo somewhere. Your JSON_MODIFY works correctly for me.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JeroenMostert 's comment

If I have a JSON @CarDataJson which is something like below

```
{
  "house": {
    "gate": [
      [
        "Car1",
        "Car911",
        "Car3",
        "Car4"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

All I need to do to modify the car911 to car2 is

```
SET @CarDataJson = JSON_MODIFY(@CarDataJson , '$.house.gate[0][1]','Car2')
```